# How to include resources file in anjuta project

Tags: gtk3, vala, anjuta

I'm trying to update a graphical project in vala, moving lot of code lines into an ui file.
I want to use template (available with glib-2.38 and GTK+3.8, something like that).

My project is managed with Anjuta and autoconf.

In the `src` directory there are

`application.ui`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.8 -->
  <template class="SpiWindow" parent="GtkApplicationWindow">
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Example Application</property>
    <property name="default-width">600</property>
    <property name="default-height">400</property>
    <child>
        <placeholder />
    </child>
  </template>
</interface>
```

`resources.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" charset="UTF-8" ?>
<gresources>
  <gresource prefix="/org/app/spi">
    <file compressed="true" preprocess="xml-stripblanks">application.ui</file>
  </gresource>
</gresources>
```

in `src/Makefile.am` I have append `--gresources resources.xml` to the `spi_VALAFLAGS`. And finally I declared The `Gtk.ApplicationWindow` like this

```
[GtkTemplate(ui = "/org/app/spi/application.ui")]
internal class SpiWindow : Gtk.ApplicationWindow {

    // Constructor
    public Window (Gtk.Application application) {
        Object(application: application);
    }
}
```

But when I compile and then run the application, there is the error message :

```
(spi:9749): Gtk-CRITICAL : Unable to load resource for composite template for type 'SpiWindow': The resource at '/org/app/spi/application.ui' does not exist
(spi:9749): Gtk-CRITICAL : gtk_widget_init_template: assertion 'template != NULL' failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need to compile the resources and include them:

```
GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES=glib-compile-resources

resources.c: resources.xml $(shell $(GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES) --generate-dependencies resources.xml)
  $(GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES) --target=$@  --generate-source $<
```

and include `resources.c` as a source file in `spi_SOURCES`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use as pattern the baobab makefile, but I missed the part where the built C file should be added to spi_SOURCES.